# 2004 Isuzu Ascender Sputtering and Possibly Misfiring

Tags: engine, troubleshooting, isuzu

Needed to get a smog check so I went to Auto Zone to find out why the check engine light was on. The code indicated that the MAP sensor needed to be replaced. So I replaced it and reset the computer by disconnecting the negative from the battery.

When I started the car it sputtered and shut off when I turned the air conditioner on. The check engine light also flashes as I drive and I believe that indicates a misfire. Before replacing the sensor the car ran fine. I replaced the new sensor with the old one and still the same problem.

Kind of loss as to what to do next.

Comment: Get the codes rechecked. Also, check to ensure anything around the MAP wasn't displaced, like wiring going to an injector or coil. It sounds as though you introduced a new issue when you replaced the MAP.

Comment: What engine is in the car? You shouldn't disconnect the battery to clear codes. The car will lose it's learned values and this may be why the engine stalled when the A/C was turned on. You should backprobe pin 2 on the MAP sensor, key on engine off the value should be 4.5-5v. key on engine running values @ idle should be 0.5-1.5v.

Comment: @Ben  Can you share with the OP howto back probe the MAP sensor?

Comment: sewing pins work pretty good. or you can buy ones that have bnc or banana style plugs. you grease the pin with dielectric grease and insert the pin along the wire.